# Apply a multi-argument function to a vector, varying only one argument

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, mapply, multiple-arguments

I would like to apply a function to a vector. My function takes multiple arguments, but I can keep the arguments the same throughout.

Here's what I've come up with, but it doesn't work. I've seen some things using `mapply` -- I'm not sure if that's what I need though.

```
add = function(x, y) x+y
sapply(1:5, add(y = 10))
```

Comment: add = function(x,y=10) x+y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can give additional arguments of a function to `sapply` like this.

```
sapply(1:5, add, y=10)
```

Just write the function name and after that you can give any number of arguments directly within sapply itself